# asp.net mvc 3 routing,resource

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, resources, routes

i use route

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Search",
                "search/{categories}/{sections}/{actions}",
                new { controller = "home", action = "search", categories = 0, sections = 0, actions = string.Empty }
                );
```

sample :  localhost:4304/search/64/0/0

Error (500 or 404) during loading resources because the way `href="../../Content/Images/favicon.ico"`

conducts not to `localhost:4304/Content/Images/favicon.ico`

but conducts to `localhost:4304/search/Content/Images/favicon.ico` (not found)

Problem with all resources (css, img, js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a good idea to reference your resource files like that.  The best way is to spit out links to them with:

```
@Url.Content("~/Css/etc.css")
```

And if you have any images that you need from CSS, just put them in a folder under CSS (example: ~/Css/Images/myImage.jpg) so you can access them from CSS like this:

```
background-image: url(Images/myImage.jpg)
```

Now, that being said, the favicon.ico should be in the root of your website and nowhere else, do you have some other situation?